# What changes, if any, are required to make the following Perl eval bullet proof?

Tags: perl, exception

```
eval {
    # here is put some code that may throw exception
    return 1;
} or do {
   my $error = $@;
   # Handle error.
};
```

1. Does the following style protect against $@ not being set
   correctly ?
2. What does the following "1;" protect against?
3. Is the "or do{" better than the saying "if ($@){ " ? If so, why?

Comment: The easiest way to bullet-proof error handling with a block eval is to use a module that implements try-catch like syntax, e.g. [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/DOY/Try-Tiny-0.12/lib/Try/Tiny.pm). The documentation lists further caveats you may be interested in.

Comment: This is clearly the result of someone applying the [recommendation of Perl::Critic](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Critic::Policy::ErrorHandling::RequireCheckingReturnValueOfEval).

Comment: @daxim That generally is not a bad thing :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Try%3a%3aTiny) documentation for discussion of the things that can go wrong when using `eval` as a `try`-type statement, how they can be avoided, and why your posted code ends with `1` (to ensure the `eval` block returns a true value if it completes successfully).

After reading it, consider using Try::Tiny instead of going through all the gyrations of making sure each of your `eval`s will function correctly as a `try`.  Laziness is the [first great virtue](http://threevirtues.com/) of a programmer, after all.

Comment: While this response proposes an alternative approach, rather than directly answering the question, I think it is the most "practical" answer, so I accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You could write above eval like,

```
my $result = eval {
    # here is put some code that may throw exception
    1;  # Why is the "1;" here ?
};
```

In this case `$result` will be `1` only if **there was no exception inside eval**, and undef otherwise.

So in this particular case `1` ensures that `or do {..}` doesn't get executed if there was no exception.

`if ($@) {..}` is perhaps more idiomatic way to do the same thing, and  `$@` is always set when `eval{..}` fails.

Comment: -1, I downvoted this because the last sentence leastwise runs counter to the advice in [P:C:P:ErrorHandling::RequireCheckingReturnValueOfEval](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Critic::Policy::ErrorHandling::RequireCheckingReturnValueOfEval). Breaking up the whole expression into several statements induces bugs on old Perls (< v5.14).

Comment: Code above is not proposal but explanation to OP question.

Comment: Still not an excuse for showing buggy code and not mentioning the circumstances.

Comment: Totally! - IMHO doco for eval should be "improved" (I would say "fixed").

Answer (score 1):

> What changes, if any, are required to make the following Perl eval bullet proof?

If I recall correctly, if you care about the contents of $@ (and not just whether it is true or not) you also need to guard against $@ being overwritten by other code that dies before you look at it (see answer to 1. below).

> 1. Does the following style protect against $@ not being set correctly ?

Yes, $@ can be overwritten in the time between the `eval` and the `if`.  The most common case for this, if I remember correctly, is the DELETE method of an object that is going out of scope (because it was in the eval) using a successful `eval`.

> What does the following "1;" protect against?

The constant true value (it doesn't have to be 1) is there to ensure that the `eval` block returns a true value.  If the code in the block die, then the block would return an empty string and the `do` block would run.  If you are certain that the last statement in the block will always be true, then it is unnecessary; however, there is no reason to not just be certain with the constant value.

> Is the "or do{" better than the saying "if ($@){ " ? If so, why?

It avoids having to store the return value of the `eval` block. You could say

```
my $result = eval {
    #do stuff
    1;
};
unless ($result) {
    # handle error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. Before I accept this answer, I'm concerned about the last block of code. Is the last code block more likely to suffer from $@ going out of scope than "or do{". My reasoning is a destructor may be called between the two lines of code in the example.  Perhaps I have this wrong? Perhaps a slight change to "or do{" or a comment at the top to avoid because of loss of scope of $@?  I'm not trying to be picky, but I am trying to have it clear for people who will cut and past this code.  Again, thank you for your detailed response.